# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 157 unexpected '<EOF>'

Tags: sql, syntax-error, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

what could possibly be wrong here??

```
create or replace temp table Whse_Role_Spend as
with 
Warehouse_Spend as (select sum(total_elapsed_time) Total_Elapsed, warehouse_name from 
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name),
Role_Spend as (select sum(total_elapsed_time) Total_Elapsed, warehouse_name, role_name from 
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name, role_name),
Credits_Used as (select sum(Credits_used) Credits_Used, warehouse_name from 
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's giving an EOF error because there's a CTE definition without a CTE query. The compiler hits the end of the statement before finding the CTE query, so it returns the EOF error.

The CTE definition also needs to define columns on the table expressions. You'll need to join the tables however you'll want them in the CTE query (at the end). This should get you past the EOF issue and close to where you can complete the statement the way you want it.

```
create or replace temp table Whse_Role_Spend as
with 
    Warehouse_Spend(total_elapsed, warehouse_name) as (select sum(total_elapsed_time) Total_Elapsed, warehouse_name from 
        "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name),
    Role_Spend (Total_Elapsed, warehouse_name, role_name) as (select sum(total_elapsed_time) Total_Elapsed, warehouse_name, role_name from 
        "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name, role_name),
    -- Add column definitions on the next table expression similar to the ones above.
    Credits_Used as (select sum(Credits_used) Credits_Used, warehouse_name from 
        "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY" group by warehouse_name)
select s.total_elapsed, 
       s.warehouse_name
from WAREHOUSE_SPEND S, ROLE_SPEND R; -- Join the CTE tables as you need them
```